# Can you write Windows services in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have written a program in PowerShell that loops and checks stuff.
I would like to convert this into a Windows service.
I've created a Windows service (in Admin->Services) but I can't start it.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing the proper interface that the system needs to call into in order to start/stop/pause/etc the service.

I can find plenty of examples when it comes to doing it in VB/C#/MS-lang but nothing about how to do it using PowerShell. Is there any documentation (or preferably code examples) out there to help with this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a scheduled task for this?

Comment: If you have found a C# example, most of the time you'll be able to adapt it to powershell, as far as it relies on system .NET.

Comment: @x0n: nice idea but scheduled tasks don't run often enough (every second) and I need it to be kicked off be another program and run with admin privs. @empo: i'm already trying to convert from a C++ example but it is a mine field and it taking forever.

Comment: Agree with x0n on using a scheduled task. If it's running on that kind of interval, write it to run in a process-sleep-process loop.  Set up the scheduled task to run under an admin account, then grant whatever is running the other program permission to start/stop the task (the other program doesn't have to be running with admin privs).

Comment: if you need to run that "often" you could simply write a wrapper using a loop construct to achieve the illusion of a persistent service running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you absolutly want to execute your PowerShell code into a service, I think you can write a C# service wrapper for PowerShell code.

You found examples of how to create a service with C#, and [it's simple to call Powershell from C#](http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/02/running-powershell-in-c.html). So I'am surprised that as small SrvAny oriented PowerShell does not exists yet.

My advice here, you better rewrite your code in C# as a service.

Comment: Never liked the idea of using the scheduler as there were too many caveats to the time I wanted to run it. I want to close this question so am selecting your answer. Powershell has very tight integration with C# and you have provided code to do it.

Comment: This question gets a lot of views but the answer is a link. Is it possible to include some relevant code into the answer?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few items at issue here:

- Are you sure that you really need a service? I agree with the comments about using the scheduler for running periodic tasks. The scheduler can start tasks as Administrator.
- Services call a special set of APIs to communicate with the Service Control Manager, so an ordinary program can't be used directly.
- The Service Control Manager uses [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to start the service process, so you need to point the SCM to an executable binary, as opposed to a script.

If you can't use the scheduler (though I strongly encourage you to try), I suppose that you could write an executable binary that acts as a service. It would then execute PowerShell and your script on your behalf. I'm thinking something like the `srvany` program that used to be included with the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit could bootstrap the service for you.

Comment: "special set of APIs to talk with the SCM, so a normal program can't be used" - I know this, this is what my whole question is about. I have already written the service in Python by extending the win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework Python class which provides all the hooks/Special-APIs needed by the SCM. So I could write a Python wrapper to call my powershell. What I'm trying to ascertain is whether or not there is something similar in powershell which will mean I won't have to install python or a C#/C++ wrapper (because I don't know C#/C++ (and am not terribly interested in learning them)).

Comment: As I wrote, the SCM can't directly invoke a script. It needs to start a Windows executable binary, you can't point it to a PowerShell script or a Python script or whatever. To properly handle the file association, the SCM would need to use ShellExecute, but as I wrote, it uses CreateProcessAsUser, so you must use a binary. If you don't want to write a service, why don't you try downloading the srvany program that I mentioned and try that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Compile Script into Service** option of PowerGUI: http://documents.software.dell.com/DOC144271

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is SrvAny.exe from Microsoft (I don't know that they support it any longer, but it has been around in the Windows 2000 Resource Kit for years. It will essentially turn just about any executable (.exe, .cmd, etc...) into a service. I have VBScripts running as quasi-services using Srvany.exe and it works on Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 (even 64 bit). It is a little limited in that it does not provide 100% service functionality (stopping a running script may be difficult) but if you now a bit about programming and the Windows environment you can adapt it to work pretty well (i.e. it will launch the program after server Restart/Startup as you would likely need from a service. There is some documentation with SrvAny.exe (although it can be a little obtuse and difficult to find). It is however Free and built for Windows so it should work for you.
I agree for simplicity that the Scheduled Task idea is worth thinking about as it is even more simplistic that srvany.exe

Answer (score 1):

http://www.firedaemon.com/

Will allows you start littery anything as a service. There are also free alternatives to this application, that does the same.

Comment: I could write one of these myself! The whole point is to just run with what's already installed on the machine. I have it set up as a service using Python but that's an extra 60MB of stuff to install whereas PowerShell is on there already. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is a legitimate alternative answer if @JPBlanc's "Write it in C#" is the selected answer. Nothing wrong with 3rd party software if it meets all requirements and use cases.