# How to create windows service to run a powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have infinite loop PowerShell (Testing purpose) script, which I want to run as a Service in Windows Server 2008 R2 (Standard).

I'm using the following command to create the Windows service,

```
sc.exe create "My PS1Service" binPath= "powershell.exe -NoLogo -Path D:\TEST\test.ps1"
```

And the result is  `[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`

But when I try to run the service **`My PS1Service`** , it return the following error

```
Windows Could not srart the My PS1Service service on Local
Computer
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
request in a family
```

Any help here !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you write Windows services in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125453/can-you-write-windows-services-in-powershell)

Comment: look at: `get-help New-Service`. Also specify the full path to `powershell.exe`

Comment: You can't just run any executable as a service. It has to respond to requests of the service control manager. Typically, in C# this would involve inheriting from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`. Are you doing anything like that in test.ps1?

Comment: @mikez , No im not doing anything like C# stuff. its just a PS1 script which has infinite loop & writes numbers into a file

Comment: Try creating service which runs with local ID. Also check the execution policy.

Comment: I was able to install service from .ps1 with nssm super quickly. It is much easier then WINSW an I don't understand the negative votes for nssm. Could somebody please comment on this?
nssm is available in chocolatey repository, hence very painless installation.

Answer (score 6):

*Due to the length of the articles I don't want to paste them in the answer.*

Check out this post which is the most comprehensive source of info I've found regarding powershell services: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703436.aspx

which links to an example powershell service:
 http://jf.larvoire.free.fr/progs/PSService.ps1

I didn't end up successfully modifying this as it was going to take me longer to read through it and understand it than it would to use a different method for my use case, but I'd certainly be going back to that if I needed to create a service in powershell in the future.

Also this: https://www.sapien.com/blog/2017/07/12/write-a-windows-service-in-powershell/

Comment: I wouldn't normally post links in an answer as they are subject to breaking but these are very long articles.

Comment: The magazine contains dead links using bit.ly. Here's the french guy repo: https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/blob/master/PowerShell/PSService.ps1

Comment: You don't need to post everything, but you should post the basics.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a very useful, simple to setup infrastructure.   @Dimas the github link was invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking all over the place for a decent way to make a PS1 into a service.
Easiest way I found is with Winsw:
https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with Non-sucking Service Manager (NSSM) as well.  https://nssm.cc/

Comment: I've subsequently used this and it works well and is easy to use

Answer (score -6):

you can create by below step:

1. First go to the path where PowerShell script located.
2. Then run below Command:
   powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File .\filename.ps1

Comment: This does not work under any scenario