# Run a powershell script inside a windows service

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have a powershell script running very well , 
I'm calling this script within a power shelle command line :

```
PS C:> .\myscript.ps1 -var1 variable1 -var2 variable2
```

I need to mount this inside a service with a stupid sc create but i couldn't find a way to launch it

any help please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you write Windows services in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125453/can-you-write-windows-services-in-powershell)

Comment: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/01/26/running-powershell-scripts-as-a-service.aspx
Basically, they recommend runing powershell.exe as a scheduled task with your script and parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Windows service wrapper](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw). It's highly configurable and provides a lot of useful options, like log rotation, service account, on failure actions and so on. It even can automatically download resources from URL and place it locally as a file, so you can host your script somewhere and have it auto updated. Here is the basic steps to get your PowerShell service up and running:

1. Download\build winsw. Version 1.x binaries can be found [here](http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/com/sun/winsw/winsw/). To build latest [winsw 2.x](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/tree/winsw-2.0) use [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) (free for open-source projects). More detailed build instructions are [here](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw#build-environment).
2. Create XML configuration file for your service. Example:

   ```
   <service>
       <id>MyPsSvc</id>
       <name>My PowerShell Service</name>
       <description>Does funny stuff with your PC</description>
       <executable>PowerShell.exe</executable>
       <logmode>reset</logmode>
       <arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -File "myscript.ps1" -var1 variable1 -var2 variable2</arguments>
   </service>
   ```

   The configuration file must have the same basename as winsw executable, i.e.:

   - winsw.exe
   - winsw.xml
3. If you plan to use your service on the PC without internet connection, [disable digital signature verification for winsw](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/tree/winsw-2.0#offline-environment-and-authenticode). To do this create file `winsw.exe.config`. Example:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <runtime>
       <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
     </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```
4. If you're running Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 and and don't want to install .Net 2.0 support, [specify .NET 4.0 runtime support](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/tree/winsw-2.0#net-runtime-40) in the abovementioned config file:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <runtime>
           <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
       </runtime>
       <startup>
           <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
       </startup>
   </configuration>
   ```
5. Install your service, running `winsw.exe install` from command line. Once the service is installed, you can start it from Windows service manager.