# PowerShell script to Service Executable

Tags: powershell, service, teamcity

I work with a DB Admin who writes a lot of PowerShell scripts to monitor different health stats on our database.

But the problem is that while they do end up in Git it is usually as compiled Services, or as the Compiled service with the script next to it.

The reason for compiling it as a Service executable is that it then fits into out monitoring platform. So we would like to keep it as a Service executable.

The way he does that today is by using PowerGui from Dell. The menu "Tools" -> "Compile Script Into Service" does it for him.

I want to do the same on TeamCity, where I can control how this is done and anyone who needs to do it can do it. But I can't use PowerGui in a TeamCity Job. Basically I want TeamCity to create the Service Executable and then upload it to S3 when built. Sounds easy, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do than from the command line.

I can find the tool PS2EXE but that doesn't create a Service executable, but just a regular executable.

I can't find a source code example to show me how to create an executable at least. If I had that, then I could probably create the tool to make the service myself.

Has anyone else done this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe check this out? http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/make-ps1exewrapper/

Comment: Thanks @ssaviers! I also found this that looks promising. http://the.powershell.zone/software/sorlov-powershell/

Comment: Use [Windows service wrapper](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw): [Run a powershell script inside a windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28454552/4424236)