# How run PowerShell script all time?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have PowerShell script that is getting WorkingSet of one process.
When WorkingSet of process is higher then defined, it will kill the process. (process will start autmaticly - this is not part of my script)

How I can make that this script will run all-time? For example now when process will be using high RAM, script will immediately run itself and will kill this process?

Is this possible or is better to do some timer that will run for example for 10 seconds? 10 sec, run script, 10 sec, run script, ....?
And how to do that?

Thnak you for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125453/can-you-write-windows-services-in-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the script in a loop and run on startup (put it in the Startup folder)

```
while ($true)
{
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    # check process and kill if necessary
}
```

Or you could set up a Scheduled Task to run at midnight and repeat every minute for 24 hours, that would be a more efficient means but I don't think it gets finer than once a minute.